# Can we limit max fps by using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding, frame-rate

I want to limit max fps when I process a video.
For example: set limit up to 30 frames per second.
If I process a video with 24 fps then I don't change fps but if I process the video with 60 fps then I change fps to 30.
Can it be done by using only FFmpeg (with filters or something else)?
I think that it can be done by using filter like this:

```
-filter:v "fps=fps='min($CURRENT_FPS,30)'"
```

But I don't know is it possible to get current fps from an expression.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?